# Bootstrap radios horizontal when sm or larger, vertical when xs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

From the [BS docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios) for styling checkboxes and radios, I want to have my radios arranged horizontally when sm or larger and arranged vertically when xs. I don't see a good way to do this based on the BS link provided above. The html for horiz and vert radios is different enough that I might have to use jquery to manipulate, but would prefer not to (change divs to inline, update label class). Suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#horizVertChange").on("click", function() {
    $(".radios-hv > div").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("radio")) {
        $(this).removeClass("radio");
        $(this).css("display", "inline");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("radio");
        $(this).css("display", "block");
      }
    });
    $(".radios-hv label").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("radio-inline")) {
        $(this).removeClass("radio-inline");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("radio-inline");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button id="horizVertChange">Toggle btw horiz and vert</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 radios-hv">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="checked" />Option one</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" />Option two</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio disabled">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3" />Option three</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the checkboxes/radios with another [**div**](https://jsfiddle.net/c1obmppy/1/)?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">1
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">2
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">3
  </label>
</div>
```

Just watch out for `col-sm-4` - dunno how many radios you have.

**Updated** based on the comment below.

You can do [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/c1obmppy/3/) if you reeeeeally want to avoid using `js`, but this way you duplicate the content, which is normally **not** a good practice.

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="RadioXS-1" id="RadioXS-1" value="option1">xs-1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="RadioXS-2" id="RadioXS-2" value="option2">xs-2 very long text here
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="RadioXS-3" id="RadioXS-3" value="option3">xs-3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs col-md-12">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">2 very long text here
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">3
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue I have with cols is that they will be a standard width. When horizontal, I want the radios to make the most efficient use of the space and not have gaps between. For example, I will have some radios with short text, **short**, and others with long text, **This is a very long label for the radio**.  1. don't want the text to wrap within a "col", 2. don't want "wasted" space.

Comment: I agree about the duplicate data. I think I'll just use js to update the div's and label's to adjust the layout.